# Unit test error - Expected Object ({ message: 'error message' }) to equal 'error message'

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write a unit test that if the method fails then show an error message but I am getting this error:

[image]

I am not sure what this means - how is 'error message' not equal to 'error message' here?

```
it('should return error when unable to update Reconciliation Flag', (done) => {
    const id = '26949';
    const subPostingId = '0';
    const isReconciled = 'false';
    const errorResponse = { error: { message: 'error message' } };
    spyBmlService.get
        .withArgs(BmlRequest.SetReconciled, {
            bwtxnid: id,
            bwpostingid: subPostingId,
            isreconciled: isReconciled,
        })
        .and.returnValue(of(errorResponse));

    service.setReconciliationFlag(id, subPostingId, isReconciled).subscribe(
        () => {},
        (error: any) => {
            expect(error.message).toEqual('error message');
            done();
        }
    );
});
```

setReconciliationFlag code:

```
public setReconciliationFlag(
    id: string,
    subPostingId: string,
    isReconciled: string
): Observable<any> {
    return this.bmlService
        .get(BmlRequest.SetReconciled, {
            bwtxnid: id,
            bwpostingid: subPostingId,
            isreconciled: isReconciled,
        })
        .pipe(
            switchMap((response: any) => {
                if (!response.error) {
                    return of(response);
                } else {
                    return throwError({ message: response.error });
                }
            })
        );
}
```

Comment: I believe that is `.setReconciliationFlag` code. Could you please provide it?

Comment: @Andrei I have added `.setReconciliationFlag` code to the question now

Answer (score 0):

This means that you expected the result to be "error message", but instead, you got an object. So you want this:

```
error message
```

Instead, you have got this:

```
{message: 'error message'}
```

You just need to use the variable correctly, so probably it is error.error.message

Comment: I tried changing the code to `expect(error.error.message).toEqual('error message');` but now getting the error 'Cannot read property 'message' of undefined thrown'

Comment: I also changed trying the code to this `const errorResponse = { error: 'error message' };` and `expect(error).toEqual('error message');` but still got error about expected object

Answer (score 0):

You are emitting a value with:

```
.and.returnValue(of(errorResponse));
```

not and error, so that in your subscription you should be receiving that value in:

```
service.setReconciliationFlag(id, subPostingId, isReconciled).subscribe(
        () => {}, // Here
        (error: any) => { // Not Here
            expect(error.message).toEqual('error message');
            done();
        }
    );
```

I'm probably missing something as I don't know the code inside the service... Anyway check your spy because it seems not to be working properly and bypassing the calls as you want.

I would recommend putting a log.console inside value() and error() functions of the subscribe so that you can see what you are receiving, or debug it within the Chrome Dev Tools in the test browser.

Comment: I just updated my question with the code for `setReconciliationFlag`

Comment: Thanks, could you share the assignation of spyBmlService? If everything is right, the spy should prevent your service to be called so the code inside won't be used. You may check that too to make sure with logs or debug.

Answer (score 0):

lets look through implementation

```
...
switchMap((response: any) => {
      ...
      } else {
        return throwError({ message: response.error }); /// here you are building "error object"
      }
    })
);
```

and test

```
const errorResponse = { error: { message: 'error message' } };
...
.and.returnValue(of(errorResponse));
...
(error: any) => {
   expect(error.message).toEqual('error message');
```

I'm not sure wether the implementation is not very good or there is a misunderstanding in test but resulting error object will be like this `{ message: /* here starts what bmlService.get returns */ { message: 'error message' }}`

so if you confirm that the implementation is perfectly fine, you should fix the assertion like this

```
expect(error.message.message).toEqual('error message');
```